# Error when I try to add date in an Excel file using Python

Tags: python, datetime, openpyxl

I would like to add the date of the 14 last days in an excel spreadsheet using openpyxl.

I use this to create an array with each date I want and then to write it in excel. Here the today date in B1.

```
import urllib2
import json
import time
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'stats.xlsx')
dest_filename = 'stats.xlsx'
ws = '<Worksheet "sheet">'
wsFR = '<Worksheet "France">'
wsIT = '<Worksheet "Italie">'
wsFR = '<Worksheet "Belgique">'

wb2 = load_workbook(filename = 'statsOrders.xlsx')
dest_filename = 'statsOrders.xlsx'
ws2 = wb2.active

for day in range(13):
    todayminus = today - timedelta(days=day)
    wsFR.cell(row=day+1, column=2, value=todayminus)
```

When I try this i got this error :

`TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

In my array the datetime are converted into string, when I print the array everything looks good.

```
['2015-12-09', '2015-12-08', '2015-12-07', '2015-12-06', '2015-12-05', '2015-12-04', '2015-12-03', '2015-12-02', '2015-12-01', '2015-11-30', '2015-11-29', '2015-11-28', '2015-11-27']
```

I do manage to solve this error.

Thanks for your time and your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your datetime object *todayminus* to a string using one of the datetime functions instead of str().

For example, try replacing the
`datetminus.append(str(todayminus))`
with

```
dateminus.append(todayminus.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

that should work

Comment: I don't think this is relevant. openpyxl will handle the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete and the tracebrack is missing which would tell us which line is causing a problem. I can run the code without problems so I suspect your worksheet is not what you think it is.

First of all, I think there is no need for an intermediate loop: you can simply assign the cells as required. Assuming you want to put the dates in the second column:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
wsFR = wb.active
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()

for day in range(13):
    todayminus = today - timedelta(days=day)
    wsFR.cell(row=day+1, column=2, value=todayminus)
```

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. I tried your code but i got this:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "stats.py", line 25, in <module>
wsFR.cell(row=day+1, column=2, value=todayminus)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cell'`

Comment: That's what I expected. What is `wsFR` in your code? It should be a worksheet object but I suspect it may be the title.

Comment: `wsFR = '<Worksheet "France">'` is a particular worksheet of my excel file. I tried with another file using `ws = wb.active`, and I got the same error.

Comment: Looks weird. Please update your post with as much of the original code as possible, especially how you're getting the worksheet.

Comment: Updated it. I use this to report stats. On the first sheet ("sheet"), I have the aggregated DATA for the 3 countries. On the others, I want for the last 14 days, the data day per day for each country.

Comment: Those are just the "id"s of the worksheets in Python. I suspect you want something like `wsFr = wb["France"]`

Comment: That has solved my issue, thanks a lot for your time!